# Storing list of parameters in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, json

I want to store list of parameters (that will define how document is going to be generated on the web page) in data base.
There is a number of item (or document) types, each type has a different set of parameters that vary (each type has it's own parameters).

Is it a good idea to store all parameters (key-value) as JSON in table's column?
Otherwise I would have to create Parameter Table for every Type and column for every parameter (10-30 params for every type).

A note: I am not going to search by parameters or something like that.
I will load the the JSON string (if I'll choose JSON), serialize it to Object and apply them on document as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no requirement of searching by parameters, To me Json seems to be more robust because you will have Object ready with information when you Deserialize it. where as if you store it in columns and table you will have to initialize class members yourself. It will also have performance benifit as there will be only one column to fetch based on *your document type*.

---

Conclusion go with Json data in Database

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should have a look at http://sisodb.com. However, it does support querying, but that is something you could turn-off and only rely on `GetById`.